# A Windows Phone 7 App for a conference

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7, azure, client-server

I need to create an app for my university.A big event will be held, there will be sessions by many speakers for the whole day. But I need to make this app customizable, In case the university changed the speakers or changed the sessions, the users then can see these changes. I've seen many apps did that. I know my question might be a little broad, but I'm asking for guidance, (because my prof supervisor has no idea neither).

I know that I'll have to get a server for that, should i use something like Azure? or is WCF good enough?

I need to know where to start.

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember a session which I saw earlier this year at the Microsoft TechDays in Belgium.

The session explained how a company built a Windows Phone 7 (WP7) application specifically for the TechDays, so that the attendees could use it to browse through the sessions, speakers, give comments...etc.

Sounds very much like the application you want to build. You can view the video of it on Channel 9, it might give you a good idea on how to proceed.

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/TechDays-2011-Belgium/TD001

Answer (score 1):

WCF is a communications protocol framework that allows you to talk to services in the format they are exposed in.  As a result, you would still need a server to talk to if you are using WCF.  Azure might be a great option for you as it is a "pay as you go" type of service (you pay for the compute time and storage you use rather than paying to have a server procured and/or set up for your use).  You would still need to build the database and populate it in Azure (or SQL Azure) but if you don't already have a server available to host your data for this conference app, then I would say Azure is a great choice.  There is actually a toolkit for WP7 that makes connectivity to Azure easier - you can find info (and download it for free) [here](http://watoolkitwp7.codeplex.com/).  It was released by Microsoft and makes a lot of the connectivity to Azure from WP7 easier.

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks, that helped a lot. should i learn WCF before dealing with Azure?

Comment: You're welcome!  I don't think you need to learn WCF as a requirement.  It may certainly help you in the future, but I don't think you need it to make this work (from what I understand of your problem space).  If you do want to learn WCF, a great place to start is the WCF portal on MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I'd agree with Paul. You don't need to know the inner workings of WCF, but I do recommend getting familiar with how to implement WCF services. You'll also want to look at OData for the service. I have a post on my blog on this, [Connecting Windows Phones and Slates to Windows Azure](http://jrozenblit.ca/tech/azure/connecting-windows-phones-and-slates-to-windows-azure), that you could check out. The video talks about a architecture that you could use to account for scale and for casually-connected devices (phones). You should also check out the [Windows Phone 7 and the Cloud](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/WAZPlatformTrainingCourse_WindowsPhone7AndTheCloud) lab in the Windows Azure Platform Training Kit. It does a really good job of going through all of this stuff.